# how can i simplify this query code its too long?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Can anyone help me to simplify this code..
i need to shorten or simplify the query code im using a stored procedure but still im need to indicate inside the "()" the details..
please help im still new here in node.js

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
try {
var reqObj = req.body;
console.log(reqObj);
req.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('SQL Connection error: ', err);
        return next(err);
    } else {
          var employee_name =  reqObj.employee_name;
          var  employee_contact = reqObj.employee_contact;
          var employee_position =  reqObj.employee_position;
```

i want to make this query short cause im planning to input lots of data so how to simplify this one??

```
        var query = conn.query(
            "CAll test3("+"'"+employee_name+"','"+employee_contact+"','"+employee_position+"')",
         function (err, result) {
            if (err) { console.log(query)
                console.error('SQL error: ', err);
                return next(err);
            }
            console.log(result);
            var test_Id = result.insertId;
            res.json({
                "test_id": test_Id 
            });
        });
    } 
}); 
   } catch (ex) { 
console.error("Internal error:" + ex); 
return next(ex);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The followings may help:

- Remove console.log
- Remove redundant assignments
- Abstract the snippet producing query string
- Use [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in ES6

```js
router.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    const makeQuery = data => {
        var { employee_name, employee_contact, employee_position } = data;

        var query = 'CAll test3(?, ?, ?)';
        var data = [employee_name, employee_contact, employee_position];

        return [query, data];
    };

    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) return next(err);

        conn.query(...makeQuery(req.body), (err, res) => {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.json({
                "test_id": res.insertId
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: when using that code i receive this ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'

Comment: my bad :) just enclose template variables in quotes

Comment: is there a way that i can remove the variable inside the CALL test3 ("here") and change it with something like a single variable?